# Chrome on android 6 clear session storage when minimizing chrome app

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, android-6.0-marshmallow, session-storage

Chrome on Android 6::

Behavior: If I set a value on session storage -> going to another app / to home screen -> going back to chrome.

Result: Session storage cleared, browser reload, and the value doesn't exist any longer.

Do you know if it's chrome / android 6 bug?
Or it's the desired behavior...?

Thanks